# wicket page expired

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, wicket

we have a java web application (using wicket)
there is several http request from my pages to other urls
some times we got page expired
page expired appear in firefox but not appear in chrome 
we think it is because of address changing done by wicket maybe for security reasons
if this think is true, how to prevent wicket from address changing

so my question is: why my page's url change Frequently
from "http://IPaddress:8080/myApp/myPage"  TO  "http://IPaddress:8080/myApp/myPage/?x=nLoy8Gx3J9W9GGieNNBndQ"  TO  "http://IPaddress:8080/myApp/?x=a8T-eIw8IixNrgLDxszosg" and so on.
note that i have a simple submit form on my page.

i ask it because we think our page expired reason is related to url changing.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: why wicket change my page's url frequently

Comment: Since you told us nothing about the actual code, I can only say that it's because that's how Wicket works. You can read more about it [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/pages.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page expired page is shown when current page being requested is not found in a page store. There could be different reasons for that:

- a http session has expired and thus all pages of this session has been erased from the the page store. Check session expiration interval with `((HttpServletRequest)getRequestCycle().getRequest().getContainerRequest()).getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval()`.
- a store size has exceeded and pages from the store has been erased.
  Check size with `getSession().getApplication().getStoreSettings().getMaxSizePerSession()`.
- Some error has occurred during saving page to the page store and now page cannot be retrieved from the page store.

Comment: is there anything like getStoreSettings() in wicket 1.4?

Comment: It should be something like this in Wicket 1.4
SecondLevelCacheSessionStore sessionStore = (SecondLevelCacheSessionStore)getSession().getApplication().getSessionStore();
DiskPageStore pageStore = (DiskPageStore)sessionStore().getStore();
pageStore.getMaxSizePerSession();